# C# thousand separator issue with decimal.tryparse

Tags: c#

I am not sure how this is able to be parsed correctly in C# but I would like it to fail where the case where the comma is not separated every repeatable three value. Example: 1,123.23 should pass but 11,23.23 should fail in my sense. But the actual output is that tryparse seems to always return true regardless of where the position of comma is before decimal.

Edit: Answer with regex is being accepted since it is found that this is a bug. Thank you.

```
 string price = "1,1,2,3.23";
 decimal outputValue = 0;
 var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);


 if (Decimal.TryParse(price, allowedStyles, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("EN-us"), out outputValue))
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Pass");
 }
```

Comment: You probably need to check the number is in the right format with a regex first,  I dont think there is anyway to do this with Decimal.TryParse

Comment: @KenTucker i thought that allow thousands was intended for this purpose where it should be checking for every three repeated value. Is this a bug or is there any currency format which accepts 1,2,3.456 and 1,23,45? since it is known as thousands separator.

Comment: There is some kind of bug involving thousands separators and `Parse` (or `Convert` or similar) methods. The only way to be 100% sure that the input format is right is checking it manually.

Comment: @KenTucker: Then what is exactly the use of TryParse(...)? This is clearly a bug. (I mean the inconsistent behaviour of TryParse)

Comment: @g.pickardou It should be taken care of automatically but, as said, this is a weird bug (I realised about it just some months ago) which apparently affects to all the converting/parsing method involving thousands separators. They work fine unless with unrealistic inputs (e.g., 11,11.2), which are wrongly assumed to be valid.

Comment: I recommend this workaround: anyDecimalString = anyDecimalString.Replace(",", ""). Then use TryParse or Parse. Then continue to work, because this will be a time killer :-) (replace comma with nothing->remove commas)

Comment: @stackdisplay Do you *require* thousands separators, or are they optional?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it should accept depends on input, meaning that it will pass regardless if it has thousand separators as long as it adhere to the format. 1234.234 will pass as well as 1,234.234

Comment: @g.pickardou thanks for the feedback. but i think that it is wrongful to replace comma with empty string as 1,2,3,4.234 is not a proper currency format.

Comment: I _still_ don't understand your question clearly. Your both `1,23.23` and `1,1,2,3.23` will pass on me.

Comment: @SonerGönül yes thats the issue. I want it to be fail. It was never supposed to be pass for the two value. It should be pass if and only if the comma is separated on the thousandth value, eg: 1,234.23 and 12,234,567.234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` doesn't enforce the comma to be on the correct place. So I think a regular expression can help you here:

```
Regex.IsMatch("11,23.23", "^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]*)?$");
```

Comment: This does not explain why "1,1,2,3.23" is passing and 11,23.23 is not passing in the original example

Comment: @g.pickardou TryParse didn't work as expected, therefore I updated my answer with a regex solution.

Comment: OK, got it. Btw, a simple replace also will do it. I think we are close to be fit the "Now they have two problems"  quote :-)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit i take this as an acceptable solution since it is being mentioned that it is a bug.

Comment: @stackdisplay ensure that your string does not contain any white spaces or it will return false for Regex.IsMatch. I just tried doing "   11,234.53" and it kick off compare with decimal.TryParse("   11,234.53"), it returns true. Just my 2 cents again :)

Comment: The check makes the code locale-dependent. Needs to use `Regex.Escape(CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator)` (or `CurrencyGroupSeparator`) instead of "`,`" I dunno if it can be blank or more than one character - if it can, additional instrumentation is needed as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this helps but, yeah I think I should try. I think my answer is a little but straight forward, just if the concern is the format, I made it compare on a .ToString("format specified"); and compare it to your "price" string. Just my 2 cents.

```
string price = "1,1,2,3.23";
decimal priceParse = 0;

if (decimal.TryParse(price, out priceParse))
{
     string shouldBeFormat = Convert.ToDecimal(priceParse).ToString("#,##0.00");

     if (price == shouldBeFormat)
     {
        // your good
     }
     else
     {
        // no good
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you discovered is clearly a bug. I strongly recommend do not stuck here, instead implement a workaround. (and also apply KISS).

Unless this code part executed zillion ad zillion times in a high math algorithm's core or any other way is performance critical, here is a simple workaround.

(Supposing the strings are using ',' (comma) as thousand separator. (and they are not decimal separator as it could be some culture)):

```
price = price.Replace(",",""); // This will not change the value when comma is thousand separator.
// Go forward to parsing
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two acceptable formats, so you can check if the number is parseable and, if so, check it is in an acceptable format:

```
string price = "1,123.23";
decimal outputValue = 0;
var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
var cul = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("EN-us");

if (decimal.TryParse(price, allowedStyles, cul, out outputValue))
{
    if (outputValue.ToString("N", cul) == price || outputValue.ToString("G", cul) == price)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pass");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi the true purpose of the question was not about accepting different acceptable format. It is about putting 1,1,23.23 in the input will result in pass in the program if numberstyles.allowthousands is applied. It should be FAIL in my sense.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a few different codes and i realized when you apply AllowThousands, the only constraint on the place of ',' is that it should be on the integer part of the number.

some results:

- "123,,3.12" => pass
- "123,,3.1,3" => fail